# Can't add legend in figure

Tags: python, qt, canvas, matplotlib, qt-designer

I want to add a legend to my figure, but it doesn't show. In the code below "forecast_canvas" is a instance of the class Canvas created in Qt Designer.

> ```
>     ax = self.forecast_canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
>     ax.plot(self.new,'--',label='observed')
>
>     ax.plot(data,color='green',label='Forecast')
>     self.forecast_canvas.draw()
> ```

Here's the code of my canvas :

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from PyQt4 import QtGui 

class   Canvas(FigureCanvas):

     def __init__(self, parent=None):
         self.figure = plt.figure()     #plt.tight_layout(pad=4)
         FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
         self.setParent(parent)
         FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
         FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
         #plt.legend()
```

I tried adding

> plt.legend()

in Canvas class but it didn't work neither.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two issues here:

1. You need to add the legend **after** creating the plots.
2. You may not be able to use `pyplot` (`plt.legend()`) because pyplot may not host any figures. (I'm saying "may" here, because I don't know the full code)
   In any case it's safer to draw the legend to a particular axes; in this case use

   ```
   ax.legend()
   ```